# invalid syntax on scraping with selenium and chromedriver

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, syntax-error

I've been using selenium to scrape data on on this site but i have this error

```
matches =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[1]/ul/li[1]')
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So i would like to know if my code below is correct to scrape all the season on this site.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
website = "https://www.premierleague.com/results?co=1&se=363&cl=-1"
driver.get(website)
sleep(10)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,('//*[@class="_24Il51SkQ29P1pCkJOUO-7"]/button')).click()
sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(driver.find_element(By.ID,('//*[@id="advertClose"]')).click()
matches = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//* 
[@id="mainContent"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[1]/ul/li[1]')
                            
matches = []                              

for match in matches:
team = matches.find_element(By.XPATH,('//* 
[@id="mainContent"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/span')).text
scores = matches.find_element(By.XPATH,('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/span/span[1]/span[2]')).text
print(match.text)
```

Comment: Could you give me the url ?

Comment: https://www.premierleague.com/results?co=1&se=363&cl=-1

Comment: What are all the data you want to scrape?

Comment: i want to scrape all the season 2020/2021 on this site in a dataframe